# ¿Cómo se le dice al que comete "tentativas de homicidios"?

Tags: solicitud-de-término, vocabulario-técnico, sustantivos, lenguaje-jurídico

¿Existe o se puede usar alguna palabra o término para aquel que comete repetidamente "tentativas de homicidios"?

Así como el que comete un homicidio es un homicida, ¿qué sería el que comete tentativas de homicidio?

Comment: ¿Podría ser _fallón_? :-)

Comment: No creo que exista una palabra para eso, aunque quien sabe, a veces uno se sorprende con estas cosas, en dos palabras: asesino torpe.

Comment: Hmmm... ¿homicinepto?

Comment: @walen Penalmente un intento de homicio y una agresión no son para nada lo mismo, aunque en la práctica quizá se pueda considerar así la intención de matar cambia la perspectiva del asunto.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sigue siendo un **homicida**.

Según el código penal, el homicidio admite las formas imperfectas, llamadas *homicidio en grado de tentativa*. Lo importante en este caso no es si el homicidio se ha llegado a consumar o no, sino la intención del que comete el delito. Si la intención es cometer un homicidio, no importa si llegó a hacerlo o si falló, esa persona es un homicida desde el momento en que su intención es cometer dicho delito.

Si la intención no era asesinar, entonces hablaríamos de *delito de lesiones*, y el calificativo sería diferente.